# Graphics Display of validated data in java

Tags: java, eclipse, graph

I Have a huge task but I'm not sure where to start with it could i have some guidance please. thanks . I have also inserted the task required below.

For this task the solution should be extended so that the data read from the file can be displayed using a two dimensional X-Y graph. The axis of the graph should be labeled using the label information specified in the data file. The values on the X-axis should begin from the  specified, with intervals which increment at a rate determined by the . The values on the Y-axis will need to be determined from the data itself. This can be achieved by identifying the minimum and maximum values within the data-set, then using the minimal value as the start value.

Each point plotted on the graph should be joined using a single line. At this stage however the graphical output does not need to be scaled, and may well not always be fully visible depending upon the input dataset. As an example the given data file shown would result in something similar to the accompanying graph.

```
Title: Effect of Age on Ability

Xlabel: Age

Ylabel: Ability

start: 0

interval: 15

0, 3, 4.2, 7, 5.1, 10, 3.2
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Read the file containing the data you have to display. For more information on how to do that see [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/).

**2)** Save the file information on a class object. Create a class Graph based on the information you're gonna read. See the following example:

```
public class Graph {
    private String title; 
    private String xLabel; 
    private String yLabel;   
    private double start;
    private double interval;
    List<Double> dataPoints;

    // Constructor
    // setters
    // getters
    ...
```

}

**3)** Use a java chart library to display the information you saved in your Graph instance. Check [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/). They have samples and everything that can help you.